# When to use CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to figure out for which commands it is safe to just use a relative path like `src/foo.c` and when to better use `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/foo.c`

The commands I need help with are:

```
add_library(myLib 
    src/foo.c)
# or
add_library(myLib 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/foo.c)


add_executable(myExe 
    src/bar.c) 
# or 
add_executable(myExe 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/bar.c)


target_include_directories(myLib 
    include) 
# or
target_include_directories(myLib 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include)


target_sources(myExe 
    src/foobar.c 
    src/baz.c) 
# or 
target_sources(myExe 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/foobar.c 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/baz.c)
```

I know that this should only be an issue when someone is using `include()` instead of `add_subdirectory()` in the top-level CMakeLists.txt. Would I even ever want to use `include()` instead of `add_subdirectory()` for a CMakeLists file containing not much more than the commands above and could maybe just don't care and use simple relative paths all the time?

Cheers,

andb